# CakePHP doesn't show uploaded picture

Tags: image, cakephp

i'm truly getting crazy!

I made a gallery with Meiouploader and PHPThumb. All is working very nice.

My uploaded images saved in folder img/uploads/images and in my database too.

But in the field for showing the images I only see the alt-text. Not the images.

But when In check the HTML-Code, I see the correct path to my images. But I don't see it.

What wrong???

Please help!

OK, here is all my code:
I think the paths are correct, because in source code in my browser i can see the image - Tag. Here is my code for Image-Model:

```
class Image extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Image';
var $validate = array(
    'gallery_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    //'img_file' => array(
        //'notempty' => array(
            //'rule' => array('notempty'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        //),
    //),
);
//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

var $belongsTo = array(
    'Gallery' => array(
        'className' => 'Gallery',
        'foreignKey' => 'gallery_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);

var $actsAs = array(
    'MeioUpload' => array(
        'img_file' => array(
            'dir' => 'img{DS}uploads{DS}images',
            'create_directory' => false,
            'allowed_mime' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png'),
            'allowed_ext' => array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'),
            'zoomCrop' => true,
            'thumbnails' => true ,
            'thumbnailQuality' => 75, 
            'thumbnailDir' => 'thumb',
            'removeOriginal' => true,
            'thumbsizes' => array(
                'normal' => array('width' => 400, 'height' => 300),
            ),
            'default' => 'default.jpg'          
        )
    )
);
```

}

Here is my code for the Images-Controller:

```
class ImagesController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Images';

function index() {
    $this->Image->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('images', $this->paginate());
}

function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid image', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('image', $this->Image->read(null, $id));
}

function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Image->create();
        if ($this->Image->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The image has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The image could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
    $galleries = $this->Image->Gallery->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('galleries'));
}

function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid image', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Image->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The image has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The image could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->Image->read(null, $id);
    }
    $galleries = $this->Image->Gallery->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('galleries'));
}

function delete($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for image', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    if ($this->Image->delete($id)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Image deleted', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Image was not deleted', true));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
}
```

Here is my code for index.ctp - View:

```
<div class="images index">
<h2><?php __('Images');?></h2>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id');?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('gallery_id');?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name');?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('img_file');?></th>
        <th class="actions"><?php __('Actions');?></th>
</tr>
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($images as $image):
    $class = null;
    if ($i++ % 2 == 0) {
        $class = ' class="altrow"';
    }
?>
<tr<?php echo $class;?>>
    <td><?php echo $image['Image']['id']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link($image['Gallery']['name'], array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'view', $image['Gallery']['id'])); ?>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $image['Image']['name']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <!--<td><?php echo $image['Image']['img_file']; ?>&nbsp;</td>-->

    <td><?php  echo $html->image('uploads' . DS . 'images' . DS . $image['Image']['img_file'], array('alt' => 'Gallery Image', 'width' => '400')); ?></td>

    <td class="actions">
        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View', true), array('action' => 'view', $image['Image']['id'])); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit', true), array('action' => 'edit', $image['Image']['id'])); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Delete', true), array('action' => 'delete', $image['Image']['id']), null, sprintf(__('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', true), $image['Image']['id'])); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
        <p>
        <?php
            echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
            'format' => __('Page %page% of %pages%, showing %current% records out of %count% total, starting on record %start%, ending on %end%', true)
            ));
        ?>  
        </p>

    <div class="paging">
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< ' . __('previous', true), array(), null, array('class'=>'disabled'));?>
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers();?>
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next', true) . ' >>', array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled'));?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Image', true), array('action' => 'add')); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Galleries', true), array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Gallery', true), array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is my code for the add.ctp - View:

```
<div class="images form">
<?php // echo $this->Form->create('Image');?>
<?php echo $form->create('Image',array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php __('Add Image'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('gallery_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('name');
    //echo $this->Form->input('img_file');
    echo $form->input('img_file', array('type' => 'file'));
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<h3><?php __('Actions'); ?></h3>
<ul>

    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Images', true), array('action' => 'index'));?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Galleries', true), array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Gallery', true), array('controller' => 'galleries', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I did all like in the tutorial of Jason Whydro, but it doesn't work well. It don't show me the pictures in this field, only the alt-text within and the width.

When I click on  link to one of these images in my source code in my browser, then he says me: There is no object. The URL coudn't found on server!!

I hope it's enough for you to see whats going wrong. I don't see it. What did you mean with User Permission? How can I fix it, if this is the problem. I work with windows 8.

Greetings...

Comment: can you provide any code snippets?

Comment: I put my complete code in there...

Comment: It's done : ) It was the path. Stupid. The seperator in this code doesn't work. I put it in a string and it works perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your path is correctly it means that when you   put this on your url bar at your  browser , it shoud appears.

When it doesn't  , could be a permission issue. Try to check your files permission to your http user.

Comment: The paths are correct, but when i click in the URL in my source code, my browser said that he don't found any object or URL on the server!